# UITextField border is different on left and bottom

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextfield

I'm having a UITextField like this:

```
lazy var mailTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField(forAutoLayout: ())
    textField.delegate = self

    let leftImgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "dd"))
    leftImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, leftImgView.image!.size.width + 22.0, leftImgView.image!.size.height);
    leftImgView.contentMode = .Center

    textField.leftView = leftImgView
    textField.leftViewMode = .Always

    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.sweet().CGColor
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

    textField.autocorrectionType = .No
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .None
    textField.spellCheckingType = .No

    return textField
}()
```

This gives me this result:

[image]

If you look closely you see that the Left and Bottom line is thicker. How is this possible? I'm telling that the border needs to be 1 thick.

Is there a way to have a border of 1 like on the top and right but then for the whole view?

Comment: testing in simulator????  make scale 100%

Comment: What does `UITextField(forAutoLayout: ())` do? Is that your custom initializer?

Comment: Thanks it was the simulator that was on 75%. forAutoLayout is something from PureLayout.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 you should move your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is issue of simulator scale ..

Make your simulator scale to 100% by `window -> scale -> 100%` or use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. This will solve your issue.